# Git: branch has lost its history?

Tags: git, branch, gitx

Something wierd has happened — my develop branch has lost all it's history till the last commit. Can anyone suggest the reason?

Last things I've done — installed that forked brotherbard GitX and started to use it (primarily for history viewing, but also tried to do on merge). But before develop was staring from master and going in parallel, 'feature-shape-fill' branch was merged into develop two times. I also did git stash in develop.

Right now git log for develop branch just shows the last commit. Doesn't says anything like 'detached'.

*
I'm already afraid of GitX (official and this fork), since last weeks smth wierd happened aswell — binary .fla file hasn't been saved for the past evening in several commits. All the text files were fine, but that binary was like 4 commits behind. Other working directory wasn't updating at all while switching between branches (I was working in console and git didn't said about any error, it was fine to him). Donno if it's smth to do with gitx?

upd:
Looks like the same problem mentioned here http://groups.google.com/group/gitx/browse_thread/thread/71a0f759d115fee5
Here's what I got:

```
$ git reflog
157cfca HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from feature-shape-fill to develop
46a6163 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from develop to feature-shape-fill
157cfca HEAD@{2}: commit: Rotated drag tip
7f6c394 HEAD@{3}: commit: TextShapesCanvas is working,
4765eed HEAD@{4}: merge feature-shape-fill: Merge made by recursive.
ed44a2c HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from feature-shape-fill to develop
46a6163 HEAD@{6}: commit: More tight packaging (thnx to TextLineMetrics),
59b6d2d HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from develop to feature-shape-fill
ed44a2c HEAD@{8}: merge feature-shape-fill: Merge made by recursive.
67d08b3 HEAD@{9}: commit: Basic grid functionality, need to add text shapes and fix resize-generation
505479c HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from feature-shape-fill to develop
59b6d2d HEAD@{11}: commit (amend): Simple retrovirus non-optomized algorithm
5ec1b70 HEAD@{12}: commit: Simple retrovirus non-optomized algorithm
b9eaf18 HEAD@{13}: commit: The most ugly suitable version of fill algorithm
757f1b7 HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from feature-shape-fill-predefined to feature-shape-fill
757f1b7 HEAD@{15}: checkout: moving from feature-shape-fill to feature-shape-fill-predefined
757f1b7 HEAD@{16}: checkout: moving from feature-shape-fill-auto to feature-shape-fill
b8e284f HEAD@{17}: commit: Auto fill first steps
757f1b7 HEAD@{18}: checkout: moving from feature-shape-fill to feature-shape-fill-auto
757f1b7 HEAD@{19}: commit: Test document created, components::TextShape base draft
505479c HEAD@{20}: checkout: moving from develop to feature-shape-fill
505479c HEAD@{21}: checkout: moving from master to develop
```

Looks like they are not lost, but how to get my history back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture you give shows that your `develop` branch is detached, if I'm not mistaken.

Since I understand it is based on the `master` branch, you could put it back on the master branch:

```
git rebase master develop
```

**Important**: first make a backup of your original `.git` directory, before trying the above, as I am not sure that this will produce the result you want.

You could also get a similar result by creating a temporary branch `develop2` from `master` and merging `develop` into it:

```
git checkout -b develop2 master
git merge develop
```

Hope this helps!  I haven't tried it, so please first back up your `.git` directory before trying the above!

Comment: As I wrote in upd I found, that I can access those lost commits, but how to get my branch (as a history of commits) back? Your way will simply create a develop branch (starting from master) that consist of a single commit, right?

Comment: @Pavel: I would guess that all commits are put back on top of master.  If you just backup your .git directory, you can very quickly try the commands above and see whether they solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To see the history of how just the develop branch changed use:

```
git reflog show develop
```

Then either checkout or add branches/tags to older commits by their SHA (or by position e.g. develop@{1}) until you find the last one that was working. For example:

```
git branch test 7f6c394
```

Looking at the log these other commits seem to be part of develop as well: ed44a2c, 67d08b3, 505479c

Move the develop branch to the last good commit. You may be able to cherry-pick the other commits back, but it really depends on what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, the parent SHA for a commit somehow wasn't set and the commit looked like it existed outside of the projects history.  The first option provided by EOL will bring your commit back into history, but will lose all of the branch history.  (At least, it did for me.)  What I ended up doing was looking through my `reflog` for the last commit before the one that sent my precious branch into limbo.  The lines I saw looked like this:

```
6d79889 HEAD@{24}: checkout: moving from online-payment-processing to gift-certificates
3da6ec3 HEAD@{25}: commit: fix computation of when to skip processing for special orders
```

Basically, a commit followed a checkout of a different branch.  (In my case, the branch `online-payment-processing` was the one in limbo and the 'moving from' message assured me that that previous commit was on my branch.)  I knew that the commit at HEAD was the one that was got messed up (as opposed to one further back in history) so I issued the command:

`git rebase 3da6ec3 online-payment-processing`

and ... *poof* ... it got fixed (after some conflict resolution) **and** my branch history was restored.